# Invalid Image if Image is large CodeIginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I'm using this code to download a file:

```
if ($file_name) {
    $file_url = $file_name;
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_url . "\"");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_url);
}
```

It downloads small file properly but when file size is large then, for Image files (like `.jpg`) saying `Invalid Image`. And for `.pdf` it is says `invalid format`. I'm using CodeIgniter framework.

**$file_name** start with `https://`

Comment: does `$file_name` give the correct path to the file?

Comment: yes if i'm putting link in browser it is opening file correctly

Comment: How large are the files you are referring to?

Also, it would be easier for you to use the download helper if you are already using codeigniter http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Codeigniter download helper.  In your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents($filePath); 
$extension = end(explode(".", $filePath);
$name = "myfile" . "." . $extension;

force_download($name, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file for

```
ini_set(); //memory limit
```

Comment: in php.ini file : memory_limit = 128M